# When is a row actually inserted into DB?

Tags: sql, database

When is a row actually inserted into the database? Is it when "INSERT" statement is finished? or when "COMMIT" statement is finished after "INSERT" statement?

Comment: As far as I understand, a row is put into a temporary table until it is verified and not waiting on a product of any other functions/triggers etc. Once COMMIT is called, it is actually written to the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later than you think. The principles here apply generally.

The whole point of the transaction log is to ensure [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) works in case of a power failure just as the INSERT finishes. The INSERT will be rolled forward or rolled back as part of the recovery phase (in most RDBMS)

So, it's more important that the transaction log entry is acknowledged as stored on the media. *Then* the INSERT can commit.

The data page containing the changed row will end up on disk *eventually* (checkpoint etc) but not necessarily at the point of successful commit.

However, the data page is in memory and available for use.

Note, an INSERT could cause a page split, indexes to be updated, triggers to fire etc so what I've said is simplified.

And it doesn't matter one way or the other when the data ends up on disk: as long as I can get the data and it's safe in case of, say, power failure

An oldie but still relevant for SQL Server: [SQL Server 2000 I/O Basics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966500.aspx)

And what I've summarized is [Write Ahead Logging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running inside a transaction, when the transaction is committed.  Otherwise, immediately.

Comment: Agreed, though depending on the isolation level the data can be visible before the transaction commits - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_level

Comment: ok. I'm using IBM DB2 here. Is there a way to actually find out this?

Comment: Here is a link for figuring that out: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21190874

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database/table implementation. It *might* just be when the transaction log is integrated - until which time the row is only inserted in the transaction log, and in memory.